# windows services using HangFire for sending email daily

Tags: c#, service, window, hangfire

I am using visual studio 2012, for send email using HangFire for sending mail but it show the below error

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

the above error shows when the debugger goes to **RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(emailService => emailService.SendEmail(), "0 9 * * *");** this statement, i also try using Tools menu ->Options -> Debugging -> General -> Uncheck this option "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" but the error was not gone please help me

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)

{

            _server = new BackgroundJobServer();

            // It will run everyday at 9:00.//
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(emailService => emailService.SendEmail(), "0 9 * * *");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
           _server.Dispose();
        }

        public class EmailService
        {
            public void SendEmail()
            {
            WCFServiceInHangFire.ReportServiceClient Service = new WCFServiceInHangFire.ReportServiceClient();
                //using web services link to send email
                Service.sendEmailToAdmin();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the IIS

Open CMD as Administrator

```
iisreset
```